# ImageView with background screen orientation

Tags: android, imageview, android-framelayout

I have the following layout:

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fanartImageView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/example_fanart"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/black.opacity.05">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_screen"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/screenImageView"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/example_screen"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@android:string/untitled"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:id="@+id/badgeWatchedImage"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_badge_watched"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:id="@+id/badgeCollectionImage"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_radius"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_badge_collection"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:id="@+id/badgeWatchlistImage"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="12.5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_badge_watchlist"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                </FrameLayout>

            </FrameLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
```

I want the screenImage in it to take as much space as possible, but with a bit of padding so you still see the fanartImageView in the background. When I do this the screenImageView does not fit inside the FrameLayout. I also tried to add a background to the parent FrameLayout of the screenImageView. But when in landscape mode only the background is resized.

Here are two screenshots to make it more clear.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you add some marging to your screenImageView?

Comment: Because that did not work. I tried that already. This was the only way to make sure the screenImageView does not grow larger than the fanartImageView.

Comment: There is another way. Apply a padding to screenImageView. See android:padding. For example: android:padding="20dp"